# Getting error while creating maven project in pom.xml file getting below error

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

**I am getting the error while creating maven project in pom.xml**

Could you please help me out why I am getting this error in my maven project?

```
CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its 
         dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:
         1.5.1, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9, 
         org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9, 
         org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.9, 
         org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.1, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:jar:1.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.2, 
         org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:2.2, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.2, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-
         plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
         Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
        - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
        - CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-testCompile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one 
         of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-
         utils:jar:1.5.1, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9, 
         org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9, 
         org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.9, 
         org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.1, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:jar:1.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.2, 
         org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:2.2, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.2, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-
         plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
         Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
        - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
```

Comment: can you post your pom.xml

Comment: post your pom. xml here

Comment: Open .m2 folder of all the jars and try to delete declared jars directory then build the project, if didn't work please change the dependencies versions then build.

Comment: Hey thanks, everyone for your valuable time I found a solution, I didn't update the maven project that's why I was getting the error in the new project I created.How to update maven project :1.Create Maven project,2.Go to Maven project right click ,3.Go to maven option,4.Click to maven option,5.Click to Update project option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't update the maven project that's why I was getting the error in the new project I created.

How to update maven project: 
1. Create Maven project,
2. Go to Maven project right click, 
3.Go to maven option,
4. Click to maven option,
5. Click to Update project option